# How to add second music folder to Cantata player?

Tags: kubuntu

I have some music in different locations and want to see it in Cantata player, but I see no way to add more than one location.

Answer (score 1):

try add a folder link in main music folder ;)

Comment: This is how to add it in FS, not in cantata ;)